# Triangle with clip-path || Background for excess "clipping"?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I have been struggling for a little while with SVG's and clip paths.

I'm trying to create a triangle clip path that will overlay a photo to give the top a "triangle" edge.

[image: photo]

I am trying to achieve exactly the same as the photo, but the triangle "reversed". Imagine that same triangle at the top of the photo instead of the bottom.

How would i achieve this? I am able to create the triangle itself with a fill color, but it will still display the image "above" the triangle.

Found this online, it does exactly what i want but it's the wrong way.

```
<svg class="bigTriangleColor2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="3 0 97 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)" d="M0 0 L51 102 L0 103 Z M0 205 L100 103 L100 2 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: [**clip path generator**](http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an SVG editor, like "Inkskape" (it's free); then:

- drag & drop your images, clip & mask what-ever you wish, then
- save as "plain SVG"
- open the saved SVG file in your favorite text editor and remove the excess code, like the "XML" declaration at the top, and any other extras.
- copy & paste the code where-ever you want it

Quick, simple, easy ;)